# What's the difference between VisualVM and Java VisualVM?

Tags: java, visualvm

I've been having some trouble with "Java VisualVM", which seems Oracle branded, and the ugly about page claims I am running verison 1.6.0_51.

In particular one thing that tipped me off I've been running an out of date or somehow ill-maintained version of this very popular dev tool is that updating available plugins fails, with:

> Unable to connect to the Java VisualVM Plugins Center because of java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching visualvm.dev.java.net found.

And indeed going to `https://visualvm.dev.java.net` gives scary warning.

So I go to `http://visualvm.dev.java.net` (no S) and download the "current" version, which is 1.3.6.  This is now just called "Visual VM" and is licensed under GNU GPL, and is void of Oracle branding.  It is also clearly nicer - the about page is better designed, it auto-updated some of its components when it opened, and going to available plugins is already populated and I can check for newest without error.

What are these two versions of this tool and how did I somehow wind up with the rotten one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A version of VisualVM ships with the JDK distribution. But since VisualVM is on its own release cycle, the version that ships with the JDK is likely to be obsolete by the time you get it.

Comment: But the current one has a lower version number.

Comment: 1.6.0_51 refers to the version of the jre (Java 6 is EOL, btw). I think it shipped with VisualVM version 1.3.1

Comment: How do you determine which version ov VisualVM is shipped with a particular JDK? There's no `--version` command line parameter, nor anything in the About dialog.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the link! I assume no way to get this from the software itself? Very strange if so...

Answer (score 0):

The Java VisualVM comes with the JDK.  VisualVM is a separate download.  In other words it refers it the distribution method - the code is the same (to my understanding).